# where can I find gov datasets (from data.gov, bea etc) in MySQL format?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, sql

Is there a place where I can find gov datasets (from data.gov, bea etc) in MySQL format? - free or paid.  I could download and parse the files of course, but wanted to check if it is already available somewhere before going down that route

Comment: You are limiting your options this way! The best way is to look for datasets -with any format- then load the data to your own my SQL dataset. Most of data are in csv/Json.

Comment: I understand,and I am going to do the same - just wanted to check if there is something already available

Comment: Why do people have an obsessions with "I want data in (x) format?".  I wouldn't suspect homework questions to be asked on the day before Christmas.  I know I've ranted about this before, but I can't find my earlier comments to link to.  And besides, for SQL databases you really don't want it as a bunch of `INSERT` statements -- you want CSV or tab-deliminated, and use [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  And there is no specific 'mySQL format' (or any SQL 'format' for data ... although some might give sufficient info to generate the `CREATE TABLE`)

Comment: Download `csv`, then use `csvsql` from `csvkit`: http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3):

you can search data.gov, this search returns over 300:
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=MySQL&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc
and this search within datasets hosted by data.gov reveals 12:
http://www.data.gov/search-results?group=site&q=MySQL